# Convert scientific notation to decimals

Tags: python, string, numbers

I have numbers in a file (so, as strings) in scientific notation, like:

```
8.99284722486562e-02
```

but I want to convert them to:

```
0.08992847
```

Is there any built-in function or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm making this answer since the top voted one has misinformation and so i can explain my improvements.

**TL;DR:** Use `("%.17f" % n).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`

---

By default Python formats to scientific notation if there's 5 or more zeroes at the beginning.
`0.00001` / `1e-05` formats to `"1e-05"`.
`0.0001` / `1e-04` formats to `"0.0001"`.

So of course `8.99284722486562e-02` will format to `"0.0899284722486562"` already.
A better example would've been `8.99284722486562e-05`. (`0.00008992847224866`)

We can easily format to raw decimal places with `"%f"` which is same as `"%.6f"` by default.
`"%f" % 8.99284722486562e-05` produces `'0.000090'`.
`"%f" % 0.01` produces `'0.010000'`.

---

By default floats display upto 17 decimal places.
`0.1234567898765432123` - (19 dp input)
`0.12345678987654321`   - (17 dp output)

So if we did `"%.17f" % 8.99284722486562e-02` we'd get `'0.08992847224865620'`. (note the extra 0)
But if we did `"%.17f" % 0.0001` we surely wouldn't want `'0.00010000000000000'`.

So to remove the trailing zeroes we can do: `("%.17f" % n).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`
(Notice we also strip the decimal point incase the number has no fraction left)

---

Also there's counterparts to `%f`:
`%f` shows standard notation
`%e` shows scientific notation
`%g` shows default (scientific if 5 or more zeroes)

Answer (score 32):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with:

```
float("8.99284722486562e-02")
# and now with 'rounding'
"{:.8f}".format(float("8.99284722486562e-02"))
```

Comment: The answer should go up to the seven, your answer goes beyond that point.

Comment: @M0dem Just add `print("%.8f" %s)` or `print("{0:.8f}".format(s))`

Comment: Try: `float('{:.8f}'.format(float("8.99284722486562e-02")))`.

Comment: For dynamic precision: `"{:.{precision}f}".format(float("8.99284722486562e-02"), precision=8)`

Answer (score 9):

The scientific notation can be converted to a floating point number with [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#float).

In [1]:  `float("8.99284722486562e-02")`
Out [1]:   0.0899284722486562

The [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#float) can be rounded with [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#format) and then [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#float) can be used on the string to return the final rounded float.

In [2]:  `float("{:.8f}".format(float("8.99284722486562e-02")))`
Out [2]:   0.08992847

---

**2022 edit for No Sound's comment:**

I learned this solution from **[here](https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-print-a-float-without-scientific-notation-in-python/#Solution_3_NumPy_format_float_positional)** *([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20220622164430/https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-print-a-float-without-scientific-notation-in-python/#Solution_3_NumPy_format_float_positional))*

The following solutions work for larger numbers.

Solution 1)

```py
import numpy as np

print(np.format_float_positional(1.32456e-12, trim='-'))
print(np.format_float_positional(1.32456e-24, trim='-'))
print(np.format_float_positional(1.32456e12, trim='-'))
print(np.format_float_positional(1.32456e24, trim='-'))

# Output: 0.00000000000132456
#         0.00000000000000000000000132456
#         1324560000000
#         1324560000000000000000000
```

Solution 2)

same as above accept this time using a lambda function

```py
import numpy as np

pretty_print = lambda x: np.format_float_positional(x, trim="-")

print(pretty_print(1.32456e-12))
print(pretty_print(1.32456e-24))
print(pretty_print(1.32456e12))
print(pretty_print(1.32456e24))

# Output: 0.00000000000132456
#         0.00000000000000000000000132456
#         1324560000000
#         1324560000000000000000000
```

Comment: It does not work in all cases. `float("1.32456e-12")` returns `1.32456e-12`

Comment: @NoSound I have just added a solution that uses numpy for you, probably not the most ideal, but better than nothing for now.

Answer (score 2):

As you may know floating point numbers have precision problems.  For example, evaluate:

```
>>> (0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1) == 0.3
False
```

Instead you may want to use the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html) class.  At the python interpreter:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> tmp = decimal.Decimal('8.99284722486562e-02')
Decimal('0.0899284722486562')
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 7
>>> decimal.getcontext().create_decimal(tmp)
Decimal('0.08992847')
```

Comment: I was scouting this topic and saw this answer, do you have an explanation to why the first statement yeilds to False?

Comment: @AhmedAlhallag See here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html "In the same way, no matter how many base 2 digits you’re willing to use, the decimal value 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a base 2 fraction. In base 2, 1/10 is the infinitely repeating fraction"