# Numpy : String to Float - astype not working?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to convert numpy string array in to a float. Actually array has numbers as strings example ['22.96' '33.96'.....]

i am using astype to convert the string numpy array to float using the below code.

```
b = a.astype(np.float)
```

The above piece of code returning something like this: `1.04200000e+02`

I tried `np.float32` and also `np.float64` but nothing working

Comment: 1. What's wrong with this behavior? 2. What input did you use to produce it? We need a [mcve].

Comment: The number you show is a float.  But tell us about `a`.

Comment: aryamccarthy is right. It is working. I'm assuming you don't want scientific notation, so see my answer below.

Comment: Updated how input looks ( i mean which is nothing but "a" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
b=list(map(float,(list(map(str,a.astype(np.float))))))
```

Then it won't print it in [scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849445/convert-scientific-notation-to-decimals).

Comment: This one also did not work out put is like this now  00000e+01   8.97000000e+00   4.10000000e+00\n   2.50000000e+00   2.50000000e+00   2.50000000e+00   2.06700000e+01\n   1.61800000e+01   2.50000000e+00   2.50000000e+00   7.76000000e+01\n   2.44300000e+01   3.41600000e+01   2.04900000e+01   1.08600000e+01\n   7.65000000e+00   2.50000000e+00   4.99000000e+00   2.50000000e+00\n   2.00400000e+01   2.5

Comment: Changed answer.

Comment: No Luck , some new error                                                                                 TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'

Comment: Awesome , it worked !!!!!! Thank you. But why cannot we convert it to a float while reading from CSV it self using genfromtxt ?                           
 a = np.genfromtxt('Discover.csv', delimiter = ',',comments='^',dtype=str,usecols=3) is my code. Upvoted your answer but i dont have reputation for that vote to show up publicly

Comment: genfromcsv does technically work, it returns a float but in scientific notation. To make it not in scientific notation, we have to convert it into a string and back into a float.

Comment: You can accept my answer. That shows publicly.

Comment: Done , figured out how to accept the answer LOL.