# How to convert a negative exponential number into a decimal number in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, scientific-notation

I'm having hard time converting the following numbers for example:

```
-1.9443404027234424e+46
```

```
-1.9443404027234425e+36
```

in a format without the scientific notation (AKA a float like `0.04256` for example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert scientific notation to decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849445/convert-scientific-notation-to-decimals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:f` [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> print("{:.0f}".format(-1.9443404027234424e+46))
-19443404027234423757622069004479676797119627264
```

Note that the result may not end with 46 zeros because of floating point precision.